# Reformat link structure to match Wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301

I migrated a blog from Weebly to Wordpress and we have links in Facebook to the old URL structure Weebly used for Posts. This portion `/1/post/` and `.html` is causing a 404 in Wordpress.

Is there a way using 301 Redirect to remove the parts of the URL that are causing the issue. Or using the [template redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) hook and regex inside Wordpress to fix this?

**Weebly**
example.com/1/post/2016/09/some-post.html

**Wordpress**
example.com/2016/09/some-post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\d+/\w+/(\d+)/(\d+)/([\w\-]+).+$ /$1/$2/$3/ [L,R=301]
```

I tested it in this website: http://htaccess.mwl.be , and it seems to work.
[image]